# Turn off aeroplane mode to make a call on Moto g2

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adb, rom-flashing, custom-roms, sim-card

I have installed Marshmallow on my Moto G2 using adb. It was a successful installation and everything was working good. Then I realized that none of my SIM was working.
My SIM card shows operator name but it can't get network.

Whenever I try to make a call, It shows me error

> Turn off aeroplane mode to make a call

I have checked and found that Aeroplane mode is already off on my device, I tried

1. Turn on/off aeroplane mode
2. Reboot my device (Multiple times)
3. Do factory reset
4. Wipe Cache and Dalvik cache
5. Do hard reset
6. Restore old Kitkat version from backup
7. Re-installation of ROM (Multiple times)
8. Insert another SIM to my device (Did not work)
9. Insert my current SIM to other device (Worked)

But nothing seems to be working for my case.
I have read each and everything related to this on internet but was not able to find any solution.

**EDIT**

I have also tried below command

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
```

to disable aeroplane mode from adb, and checked with below

```
adb shell settings get global airplane_mode_on
```

It returns `0` that means Aeroplane mode is off but issue is still there. I still see the error message and can't use my SIM.

**EDIT 2**

I run below commands with OKAY response.

```
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
fastboot erase modemst1
fastboot erase modemst2
fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
```

Used `*#*#4636#*#*` and changed network type to `WCDMA preferred`

Checked `IMEI` using `*#06#` and its valid.

**EDIT 3**

I found that there is no "Cellular Network" option available on my device. Could this be the issue for not reaching out network?

Below is output for getvar all

```
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: 4887
(bootloader) product: titan
(bootloader) secure: yes
(bootloader) hwrev: 0x8400
(bootloader) radio: 0x5
(bootloader) emmc: 16GB ID=15 REV=07 PRV=0B TYPE=57
(bootloader) ram: 1024MB Hynix S4 SDRAM DIE=4Gb
(bootloader) cpu: MSM8226 CS
(bootloader) serialno: ZX1DXXXXXX
(bootloader) cid: 0x0007
(bootloader) channelid: 0xc0
(bootloader) uid: 2B8DXXXXXX000000000000000000
(bootloader) unlocked: yes
(bootloader) securestate: unlocked
(bootloader) iswarrantyvoid: yes
(bootloader) mot_sst: 3
(bootloader) max-download-size: 536870912
(bootloader) reason: Reboot mode set to fastboot
(bootloader) imei: 3533210XXXXXXXX
(bootloader) meid:
(bootloader) date: 09-11-2014
(bootloader) sku: XT1068
(bootloader) battid: (null)
(bootloader) iccid:
(bootloader) cust_md5:
(bootloader) max-sparse-size: 268435456
(bootloader) current-time: "Tue Apr  4 23:50:50 UTC 2017"
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[0]: motorola/titan_retla_ds/titan_umts
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[1]: ds:6.0/MPB24.65-34-3/3:user/releas
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[2]: e-keys
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[0]: Blur_Version.24.81.3.titan_retla_
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[1]: ds.retla.en.01
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom[0]: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom[1]: .04.04.02.048.045
(bootloader) version-baseband: MSM8626BP_1032.3116.99.00B DFLT_FSG
(bootloader) kernel.version[0]: Linux version 3.4.42-g0a0ded4 (hudsoncm@
(bootloader) kernel.version[1]: ilclbld86) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #1 S
(bootloader) kernel.version[2]: MP PREEMPT Mon Aug 22 14:30:22 CDT 2016
(bootloader) sdi.git: git=MBM-NG-V48.87-0-gdc5aeaf
(bootloader) sbl1.git: git=MBM-NG-V48.87-0-gbffe41a
(bootloader) rpm.git: git=MBM-NG-V48.87-0-gbe53f43
(bootloader) tz.git: git=MBM-NG-V48.87-0-g31cba28
(bootloader) aboot.git: git=MBM-NG-V48.87-0-g1b80345
(bootloader) partition-type: raw
(bootloader) partition-size:
(bootloader) qe: qe 1/1
(bootloader) productid: ZX1D62FVGF
(bootloader) sutinfo:
(bootloader) ro.carrier: retin
all: listed above
finished. total time: 0.340s
```

I am using **XT1068_TITAN_RETLA_DS_6.0_MPB24.65-34-3_cid12_CFC.xml.zip** dated **2017-02-05 19:29** from this [source](https://firmware.center/firmware/Motorola/Moto%20G%20%282nd%20gen-2014%29/Stock/XT1068/)

I used **EasyInstaller.bat** to install on my mobile.

Is there any other thing I can try?

Comment: I have checked everything related to this on @xda forums. All above steps I have found from there only but none seems to be working.

Comment: This is almost always a mismatch of radio firmware and kernel. Try reflashing the radio stack. I am assuming your IMEI is valid and not 0?

Comment: @acejavelin, thanks for the reply but I am not sure what is a radio firmware. can please guide me with anything. Also my IMEI is valid and not 0.

Comment: The modem "stack" is the modem Firmware, reflash from your firmware image with fastboot... 'fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin', 'fastboot erase modemst1', 'fastboot erase modemst2', and 'fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn' and verify OK for each step. You must use the same firmware image your boot.img is from

Comment: I run every command as you suggested and found OKAY for each but the issue is still there

Comment: Can you append the output of "fastboot getvar all" and mask out the IMEI & Serial Number to the original question please? Also, a link to your ROM image source and flashing method (or a pastebin link to an actual flash from your terminal log or command prompt)?

Comment: @acejavelin, added more details to question.

Comment: Hmm... This is the Indian version right (ro.carrier=retin)? Shouldn't you be using XT1068_TITAN_RETAILDSDS_6.0_MPB24.65-34-3_cid7_CFC.xml.zip? That is for the Indian variant or at least I believe so... Also, I would recommend flashing the firmware manually so you can see if any part fails. Otherwise I got nothing, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @acejavelin, I will try flashing suggested ROM. Thanks for your great support. One last thing, how do you know which zip file is for Indian version?

Comment: I don't know for certain... But RETLA is for Latin America and RETAILDSDS is for India from what I can tell... If you examine the flashfile.XML file in the ROM zip, you can determine the proper fastboot commands to do it manually. I can probably post an answer later today on the exact process.

Comment: Thank you very much @acejavelin, I will follow `flashfile.xml`, If you can answer that will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using the incorrect firmware for your device... Your device is Retail India (RETIN), but the firmware image you are using is Retail Latin America (RETLA). The correct firmware for Retail India is RETAILDSDS (don't ask me why, I have no idea what it stands for other than Dual SIM something).
A mismatch of radio firmware to the hardware in your device can cause the operating system to think you are in airplane (aeroplane) mode.

Assuming you have the proper drivers and fastboot installed, use [this](https://firmware.center/firmware/Motorola/Moto%20G%20%282nd%20gen-2014%29/Stock/XT1068/XT1068_TITAN_RETAILDSDS_6.0_MPB24.65-34-3_cid7_CFC.xml.zip) file and extract it to your fastboot directory, or any known directory if fastboot is in your path. Open a elevated privilege command window, in Windows click Start and type `cmd` and then right-click on cmd.exe and select Run as Administrator or in Linux open a terminal window and enter `sudo -i` and your password, and navigate to the folder where you extracted the firmware file's contents.

Then enter these commands manually, one at a time (it's OK to copy/paste them individually, just don't do the whole thing at once):

`fastboot oem fb_mode_set`
`fastboot flash partition gpt.bin`
`fastboot flash motoboot motoboot.img`
`fastboot reboot-bootloader`
`fastboot flash logo logo.bin`
`fastboot flash boot boot.img`
`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3`
`fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin`
`fastboot erase modemst1`
`fastboot erase modemst2`
`fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn`
`fastboot erase cache`
`fastboot erase userdata`
`fastboot oem fb_mode_clear`
`fastboot reboot`

If ANY step fails, or gives any response other than OKAY, check the command and try again. In some cases the modems will need to be done be done 2-3 times. If you get a "Preflash validation error" on the partition table (gpt.bin) it is OK to skip that file (ONLY if you get that error), but you must do each step after that.

The first boot on Marshmallow can take a long time, give it at least 20 minutes after the final reboot to come up to the setup wizard.

This should bring the modem/radio firmware in line with the boot image and the hardware radio and allow you to get normal service again.

Good luck!

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Awesome! Glad I could help... Sorry for all the questions but it was the only way to get to the solution.